# Change active tab after user click in a specific link is not working

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have this link "http://proj.test/congress/1/congress-test/registration" where the user has a form to register in a congress. Its a muli step form, in the step 2 there is a message informing the user that he was registered with success.In this message there is a link "My Tickets":

```
 <a href="{{route('user.index', ['user' => Auth::id()])#myTickets}}"My Tickes</a>
```

Route for the link:

```
Route::get('/user/profile', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@index',
    'as'   =>'user.index'
]);
```

When the user click in "My Tickets" he goes to " "proj.test/user/profile?user=1" that is the page to edit some user account settings. In  this page there are some tabs like "General Info", "My Tickets".

The default tab is "General Info", that is the tab to update some user general info.

**Doubt:** My doubt is how to turn the "My Tickets" tab active when the user in the congress registration page (http://proj.test/congress/1/congress-test/registration) clicks in "My Tickets".

Do you know how to achieve that?

The links to the tabs "General info" and to the tab "My Tickets" in the uer account page (proj.test/user/profile?user=1) have this hrefs below:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills bg-light-gray account_options" role="tablist">
 <li class="">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#generalInfo" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">
        <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="d-none d-lg-inline-block">General Info</span></a>
</li>
<li class="disabled">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#myTickets" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">>MyTickets</span></a>
</li>
...
</ul>
```

Then the tabs are like below:

```
<div class="tab-content  bg-white" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active clearfix" id="generalInfo" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
        <form method="post" action="{{route('user.updateGeneralInfo')}}" class="clearfix">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        ...
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane clearfix fade" id="myTickets" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I was trying with jQuery like:

```
var path = window.location.href;
    alert(path);
    $('.account_options a').each(function () {
        if (this.href === path) {
            $('a[href="#' + path + '"]').addClass('active');
        }
    });
```

But its not working.

The "My Tickets" dont become active when the user clicks in the link "     `<a href="{{route('user.index', ['user' => Auth::id()])#myTickets}}"My Tickes</a>`" in the registration page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to remove the 'active' class on tabs that are not active when switching.

Try this something like this:

```
  var targetId = '#' + $(this).data('target');

  if ($(this).href === path) {
      $(this).addClass('active');

      $(targetId).show();
  } else {
      $(this).removeClass('active');

      $(targetId).hide();
  }
```

Another option is to not use the url but just an event listener. Example:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.account_options a', function (event) {
        $('.account_options a').each(function () {
            var targetId = '#' + $(this).data('target');

            $(this).removeClass('active');

            $(targetId).hide();
        });

        var targetId = '#' + $(this).data('target');

        $(this).addClass('active');

        $(targetId).show();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks but also dont works, when the user clicks in the link " <a href="{{route('user.index', ['user' => Auth::id()])}}"My Tickes</a>" in the registration.blade.php and goes to the page where is the tabs the "My Tickets" tab dont stay active.

Comment: It seems you are loading a new page when switching tabs?
In that case you shouldn't use javascript to enact the 'active' class but just use blade instead.

Comment: Yes, the tabs are on a different page, the link "My tickes" it is in the registration.blade.php, the edit user account page where there are the different tables are in the "users/edit.blade.php". My doubt about how to when the user click in "My Tickets" in the registration.blade.php in the "users/edit.blade.php" the tab "My Tickets" become active.

Comment: Okay then don't use javascript but add the active tab with blade.

For example if you are using named routes:

`class="@if(Route::is('general-info')) active@endif"`

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is that I have a named route to the "/users/edit.blade.php" that is  "Route::get('/user/profile', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@index',
    'as'   =>'user.index'
]);". But then in the user edit accout page, the tab links are static, there is no routes for that links, that links are just to change in the same page between the different tabs.

Comment: Ah I see. So I misunderstood you. You do need to use javascript.
It seems you are comparing the href attribute to the full path?
if(this.href === path)
but you need to have the #generalInfo part and compare it to that.
could you do some logging to see whether the comparison is going wrong?

Comment: Maybe the issue is because in the registration.blade.php when the user click in "My tickets" he is redirected to "http://proj.test/user/profile?user=1" so the alert(path) shows "http://proj.test/user/profile?user=1", so there is no information about the tab that should be active, in this case "My tickets" tab.

Comment: But even if I add manually the #myTickets like "http://proj.test/user/profile?user=1#myTickets" the "My Tickets" tab dont become active, the "General Info" remains active.

Comment: you need to parse the path to retrieve the "#myTickets" part.

Another option is to not use the url but just an event listener. Example:
    `$(document).on('click', '.account_options a', function( event ) {
       $('.account_options a').each(function () {
             $(this).removeClass('active');
       });
       $(this).addClass('active');
    });`
The only reason not to do it like this is if you want to enable a user to load the page with a specific tab opened.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain how that parse to retrieve "#myTickets" could be? But if accessing manually "proj.test/user/profile?user=1#myTickets" is not working maybe that parse to retrieve "#myTickets" also dont works.

Comment: If you are just starting out with jQuery it will be easier for you to try to use event listener instead like I mentioned. I will update the answer.

Comment: With "var path = window.location.href;
                alert(path);
                $('.account_options a').each(function () {
                    if (this.href === path) {
                        $(this).addClass('active');
                    } else {
                        $(this).removeClass('active');
                    }
                });" when the "My Tickets" is clicked the active tab changes to "My Tickets" but only the tab link changes color but the tab content dont changes it remains the content of the tab 1 (#generalInfo).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169869/discussion-between-mkk-and-jow).